# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in SQLite on Mac OS

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, exc-bad-access, fmdb

I'm pulling and pushing data from an sqlite database. I use the FMDatabase cocoa wrapper.

I'm pulling and pushing data from multiple threads, but I made sure that more then one transactions never happen at the same time.

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after a few hundred call at the database but never at the same time. It's also not memory related (I've tried NSZombies and looked at the memory management of parameters).

Here is the stack and the code :

[alt text http://grab.by/1VwY](http://grab.by/1VwY)

```
FMResultSet* result = [db executeQuery:@"select latitude, longitude from cache where name = ?", name];
[result next];

NSString* latitude = [result stringForColumn:@"latitude"];
NSString* longitude = [result stringForColumn:@"longitude"];
```

I've got no idea, does somebody has one?

Comment: Have you tried logging (or printing within the debugger) the value of `name`? What happens when you do?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly 'normal'. It's an expected name.

Comment: "It's also not memory related." Yes it most definitely is. EXC_BAD_ACCESS is precisely memory-related.

Comment: I know, I meant that it wasn't at least my memory management that was in fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the relevant code in `FMDatabase`, it seems the `sqlite_bind_text()` routines uses the `SQLITE_STATIC` parameter to bind the result `NSString`'s `-UTF8String` method (which returns an `autoreleased` pointer).

This means `SQLite` assumes that the text storage will remain valid for as long as the text remains bound, while the `-UTF8String` return is only valid for the current autorelease context. If you're using the same `FMResultSet` over multiple threads or function calls, changing that parameter to `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` would be much safer.

I'd suggest making that change in every `sqlite3_bind_text()` call and seeing if it still crashes.  If that fixes it, you may want to report it back to the developer as a possible improvement.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks, testing that out!

Comment: Didn't make any change… :/ Still crashing the same way.

Comment: Oh well. I suspect we'll need to see more of the code to figure out what was wrong.  One thing you can do to help is to download the sqlite amalgamation and compile your project with that.  That way you'll have full debugging symbols, and you can turn on the SQLITE_DEBUG preprocessor macro.

Comment: Cleaned and rebuild the project and it works! Thanks! Will report that to Gus too!

Comment: gcamp, did you solve this problem? Changing to transient did not solve it for me (I am not using result sets over multiple threads)